# How to store Foreign Keys via PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

In a relational database which is the best way to store a foriegn key, or relate a key, not sure how best to phrase it.

For example if you had tables:

User

- ID
- Name
- Email

Email:

- ID
- Email

This is not a table I am actually creating just simple enough to get the idea across.

In the user table if I would create a key with the ID then when I select the user table the ID of the email is the value in the email field. I can reference the actual email field, this fixes that issue, but is that not wasteful?

I am using PHPMyAdmin to setup the databases and keys.

Any advice the best way to do this?

Comment: You can write mysql query to create foreign keys for the table which you are concerned right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin provides a Graphical User Interface (GUI) to MySQL operations.

The best way to do this is databases, which I presume you will have already created, is to simply run a quick query!

MySQL looks pretty scary, but its actually really simple, once you grasp the concept of it!

By looking at your example, you'll most likely be looking to run a query like this one. (This is rough pseudo and may not run in itself)

```
ALTER TABLE User
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Email(ID);
```

Easy peasy! :)

The best resource for finding out more about the syntax required is over on W3 Schools! [This](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_foreignkey.asp) is the article you'll want to look at!

> Edit
>
> As a general database rule, I'd recommend making all your column names (fields) unique! This avoids confusion. For example, you could use `UserID` and `EmailID`.

Comment: I understand that bit using Mysql, sometimes I will use Mysql instead of the GUI. The issue I am having with Mysql as well is that I want to be able to see the actual email in the user table when I view the rows or select all of the user rows (for example). I can't see to do that if I reference the ID, however if I reference the email then I can, but I was not sure whether I should be referencing large fields such as name, text identifications and emails in keys.

Comment: In some cases, email addresses are used as primary keys (using the email instead of ID). But this can cause issues if you ever have to update an email, it gets really messy!

I'm not familiar enough with PhpMyAdmin to suggest any other work arounds, but one thing you may be able to do is create seom kind of admin panel, through which you can layout data however you like! But that wholly depends on what the purpose of having the aforementioned view is!

Comment: Alright I see what you mean, I might go with referencing the email field in the key and keeping it uinique but continue having an ID with Auto Increment Primary Key in both tables. This means if someone wants to update their email it would just create a new email row.

However I already planned to create an admin panel so I shall have to mess around and see what works! Thanks very much for your advice!